# Spree Error: --migrate=true is not a rails project

Tags: installation, spree

I cannot install a spree store in my application because of this error I keep getting:

```
spree install
Would you like to install the default gateways? (Recommended) (yes/no) [yes] y
Would you like to install the default authentication system? (yes/no) [yes] y
Would you like to run the migrations? (yes/no) [yes] y
Would you like to load the seed data? (yes/no) [yes] n
Would you like to load the sample data? (yes/no) [yes] n
 gemfile  spree
 gemfile  spree_gateway
 gemfile  spree_auth_devise
     run  bundle install from "."
--migrate=true is not a rails project.
```

here is my gemfile...

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails_12factor'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'devise'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'twitter-bootswatch-rails'
gem 'twitter-bootswatch-rails-helpers'
gem 'rails', '4.1.6'
gem 'spree_cmd'
gem 'spree', '2.3.4'
gem 'spree_gateway', :git => 'https://github.com/spree/spree_gateway.git', :branch => '2-3-stable'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', :git => 'https://github.com/spree/spree_auth_devise.git', :branch => '2-3-stable'
```

then, when i run the other command, rails g spree:install, this is what happens:

```
rails g spree:install
Would you like to install the default gateways? (Recommended) (yes/no) [yes] y
Would you like to install the default authentication system? (yes/no) [yes] y
Would you like to run the migrations? (yes/no) [yes] y
Would you like to load the seed data? (yes/no) [yes] n
Would you like to load the sample data? (yes/no) [yes] n
     gemfile  spree
     gemfile  spree_gateway
     gemfile  spree_auth_devise
         run  bundle install from "."
--migrate=true is not a rails project.
/Users/claymccullough/Desktop/cybocars/config/initializers/devise.rb:132:in `block in <top  (required)>': undefined method `expire_all_remember_me_on_sign_out=' for Devise:Module   (NoMethodError)
from /Users/claymccullough/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise.rb:288:in `setup'
from /Users/claymccullough/Desktop/cybocars/config/initializers/devise.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/claymccullough/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
from /Users/claymccullough/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
from /Users/claymccullough/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/claymccullough/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
from /Users/claymccullough/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:648:in `block in load_config_initializer'
from /Users/claymccullough/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
from /Users/claymccullough/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:647:in `load_config_initializer'
from /Users/claymccullough/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:612:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
from /Users/claymccullough/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `each'
from /Users/claymccullough/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:611:in `block in <class:Engine>'
from /Users/claymccullough/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /Users/claymccullough/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /Users/claymccullough/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /Users/claymccullough/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
from /Users/claymccullough/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/claymccullough/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:210:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/claymccullough/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/claymccullough/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:209:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/claymccullough/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
from /Users/claymccullough/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
from /Users/claymccullough/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:203:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/claymccullough/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/claymccullough/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
from /Users/claymccullough/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/claymccullough/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
from /Users/claymccullough/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /Users/claymccullough/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
from /Users/claymccullough/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
from /Users/claymccullough/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
from /Users/claymccullough/Desktop/cybocars/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/claymccullough/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
from /Users/claymccullough/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
from /Users/claymccullough/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
from /Users/claymccullough/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/claymccullough/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
from /Users/claymccullough/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/application.rb:276:in `require_environment!'
from /Users/claymccullough/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:147:in `require_application_and_environment!'
from /Users/claymccullough/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:133:in `generate_or_destroy'
from /Users/claymccullough/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:51:in `generate'
from /Users/claymccullough/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
from /Users/claymccullough/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

If anyone else who has faced this problem and solved it could help, that would be great. Thanks for your time. Also, I did not have this issue before I downloaded OS X Yosemite.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem. The way I resolved it was by following Spree's documentation instructions for installation verbatim:

```
gem install spree
rails _4.2.1_ new my_store
spree install my_store
```

Originally I was not including '__4.2.1_' in my rails new command